# Burning bin file to FPGA

Tags: fpga

I have a bin file which contains 8-bit space seperated binary data and I want to load it in memory. In simulation it works fine, the readmemoryb command loads data in reg memory. Is there any way to burn that data in FPGA memory since I want to show that data on nexys 4 board as well

Comment: You need to specify the type of FPGA in your question and also the type of memory to be used.

Comment: A [Nexys 4](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/programmable-logic/nexys-4/start) uses an [Artix-7](https://www.xilinx.com/products/silicon-devices/fpga/artix-7.html), a Xilinx device. See [Vivado Design Suite User Guide: Synthesis](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_3/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) Chapter 4 Initializing RAM Contents, Specifying RAM Initial Contents in an External Data File.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your data into one of the supported formats for memory initialization. Then you can specify the file when you configure the RAM.

A .mif file for an Intel FPGA, for example, looks like this:

```
DEPTH = 32;            % Memory depth and width are required   %
                       % DEPTH is the number of addresses      %
WIDTH = 14;            % WIDTH is the number of bits of data per word %
%  DEPTH and WIDTH should be entered as decimal numbers        %

ADDRESS_RADIX = HEX;   % Address and value radixes are required  %
DATA_RADIX = HEX;      % Enter BIN, DEC, HEX, OCT, or UNS; unless  %
                       % otherwise specified, radixes = HEX    %
-- Specify values for addresses, which can be single address or range
CONTENT
BEGIN
[0..F]: 3FFF;   % Range--Every address from 0 to F = 3FFF  %
6     : F;      % Single address--Address 6 = F %
8     : F E 5;  % Range starting from specific address %
                % Addr[8] = F, Addr[9] = E, Addr[A] = 5 %
--
END;
```

[source](https://www.mil.ufl.edu/4712/docs/mif_help.pdf)

Comment: Yes, except that the asker neglected to mention that their board uses a Xilinx chip.

Comment: @ChrisStratton that’s why I said for example.