# Embedding data in RAM during synthesis

Tags: fpga, verilog, synthesis

I have designed a CPU that works in simulation using Verilator, and would now like to test it in hardware on an FPGA. A quick way to get to the testing phase would be to embed a program to run on the CPU into memory on the FPGA itself, then read instructions from it.

I have read about the `$readmemh(...)` function that reads data from a .mem file into some memory structure but I am not sure how to make this happen during synthesis. I tried using an `initial` construct but learnt that this was only run in simulation. How would I go about embedding data into the FPGA at synthesis?

In the future I would devise some way of loading a program at startup over serial or reading instructions from something like flash storage that could be programmed separately (similar to how an ATMega is programmed).

My RAM module is:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
`define SIZE 512
`define ADDR(address) address[8:0]

module mem(
    /* verilator lint_off UNUSED */
    input [15:0] address,
    /* verilator lint_on UNUSED */
    input [31:0] data_in,
    output reg[31:0] data_out,
    input read,
    input write,
    input clk
);

reg[7:0] data[`SIZE-1:0];

always @(negedge clk) begin
    if (write) begin
        data[`ADDR(address)] <= data_in[7:0];
        data[`ADDR(address) + 1] <= data_in[15:8];
        data[`ADDR(address) + 2] <= data_in[23:16];
        data[`ADDR(address) + 3] <= data_in[31:24];
    end
    else if (read) begin
        data_out[7:0] <= data[`ADDR(address)];
        data_out[15:8] <= data[`ADDR(address) + 1];
        data_out[23:16] <= data[`ADDR(address) + 2];
        data_out[31:24] <= data[`ADDR(address) + 3];
    end
end

endmodule
```

The `data` structure is where I would like to embed the bytes from a file.

Comment: "I tried using an initial construct but learnt that this was only run in simulation" - `initial` blocks will work with many FPGA synthesis tools to set the power-on values of registers and memories

Comment: See [Burning bin file to FPGA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/420978/11683).

Comment: First you need to find out if the particular FPGA block memory resource you are targeting is capable of being initialized from the bitstream, if it is, pursue the appropriate method.  Some types cannot be, in which case you'd need your own logic to initialize the state, either by using hooks that let you read additional data beyond the end of the bitstream from the configuration flash, or by reading from some other form of non-volatile storage.

Comment: Why does it have to be RAM?

Comment: @BruceAbbott It doesn't necessarily. I just need a way of retrieving some predefined data.

Comment: What FPGA are you targetting?

Comment: @DonFusili I'm targeting an Arty-A7 which has an Artix-7 35T fpga (https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/programmable-logic/arty-a7/start)

Comment: Then Tom Carpenter is right on the money: `initial` blocks synthesize fine for the Artix-7 line provided you're using official Xilinx tooling. Other toolchains might work as well.

Comment: Thanks all, I realised the reason why readmemh wasn't working for me was that the size of the structure being written to has to be the same size as the data being read in. This may be a normal constraint or it could be down to my setup but it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I realised the reason why `readmemh` wasn't working for me was that the size of the structure being written to has to be the same size as the data being read in. This may be a normal constraint or it could be down to my setup but it fixed the issue for me.